# Get exactly `n` unique randomly sampled rows per category in a Dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I want to get exactly `n` unique randomly sampled rows per category in a Dataframe. This proved to be involve more steps than the description would lead you to believe.

```py
n = 4
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1],
                   'value' : range(12)})


category_counts = df['category'].value_counts()
categories_with_count_above_threshold = category_counts[category_counts >= n].index

# rows with infrequent categories are filtered out
df = df[df['category'].isin(categories_with_count_above_threshold)]

# sample exactly x rows per category
df = df.groupby('category').sample(n)
```

This goes through the whole DataFrame quite a few times. With a bigger DataFrame this can become quite time consuming. Is there a way to simplify this expression?

PS: requires `pandas` >= 1.1 for the `DataFrameGroupBy.sample`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [`DataFrameGroupBy.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html?highlight=filter#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter)  (I don't have recent pandas on this machine so I can't test it).

```
n = 4
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1],
                   'value' : range(12)})

# sample exactly x rows per category
df = df.groupby('category').filter(lambda x:x.size >= n).sample(n)
```

Comment: Filter sadly does not return groups, so sample works on the whole DataFrame and I get n rows back instead of n rows _per group_. As it stands, I would just have to do another `groupby('category')` between `filter` and `sample`.

Comment: Also, `filter` passes the groups as DFs to the lambda function and size returns <n_rows * n_columns> for DFs, so you would have to call `len` instead.
In the end the multiple groupby could not be avoided and the query has to look like this afaict:
`df = df.groupby('category').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= n).groupby('category').sample(n)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's code using `.apply()`, that makes a single pass through the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1],
                   'value': range(12),
                   'other': list('abcdefghijkl')})

def pick(group, n):
    """Return n random rows from groups that have at least n rows"""

    if len(group) >= n:
        return group.sample(n)

# sample exactly x rows per category, iff there are at least x in the catgory
x = 4
df1 = df.groupby('category').apply(pick, x).reset_index(drop=True)

df1
```

output:

```
    category    value   other
0      1         3      d
1      1        11      l
2      1         6      g
3      1         9      j
4      2        10      k
5      2         1      b
6      2         4      e
7      2         7      h
```